# Install 13.04 to a specific partition

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a machine that already runs Windows 7.

Before installing, I shrank the Windows partition and added a new ext2 partition called /dev/sda4 using GParted.

When I rebooted with the installation media inserted and started the installation process, Ubuntu reported "This hard drive is empty. Do you wish to erase/format(?) it? Then, it gave me a number of options.

How do I proceed from this point and install to /dev/sda4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the option `something else`. From there you can select the `/dev/sda4` partition and assign (mount point) it to root (/).

Keep in mind that ext2 filesystem is considered as deprecated nowadays. Use ext4 instead.

[image]

[image]